# Updating display on JS calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I want to have my calculator to display "0" when cleared or no other numbers have been entered but when I start adding numbers I want the 0 to be replaced. Currently when I enter any number it replaces the number on the display to the number entered.

```
this.currentDisplay = "0"

numberData(number) {
        if (number === "." && this.currentDisplay.includes("."))
        return
        if (this.currentDisplay = "0") {
        this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString().replace("0", number.toString())
        }
        else {
            this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString() + number.toString()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `number` (the real number inputted) should be split from `currentDisplay` (the value you display), then you can simply do your checks inverse, and if `number` not set, set currentDisplay to 0 else set it to number, i.e `this.currentDisplay = number || 0` you don't need all this string concatenating, for the state of the values and sums shouldn't be done via concatenation but rather in some array/stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on the this condition:

```js
if (this.currentDisplay == "0") {
   ...
}
```

In your code you are assigning `this.currentDisplay = 0`, you should compare with `==` or better `===` to compare the types of the variables too.